# How do I create key mappings for Windows and/or nano Shortcuts?

Tags: key-bindings, buffers, save

Having used text editors (mainly Notepad/++) and some IDEs on MS Windows, I've become familiar with their <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> shortcuts to the point that I use them automatically. Having used `nano` on a GNU/Linux machine for many years, I tend to automatically use its <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key shortcuts (particularly `^O` and `^X` as `nano` represents them) when editing text in either `nano` or insert mode in `vim`. Consequently, text I type in `vim` tends to be littered with `^S` and `^O`, instead of actually saving (writing out the buffer to file) at that point. (It seems to me that `<C-s>` currently isn't mapped to anything, despite the fact that some terminals use it for a special purpose.)

To stop that happening, I'd like to create the following mappings in `~/.vimrc`, but my efforts so far result in `vim` issuing a warning about not finding a mapping (because I'm clearly doing it wrong):

- `<C-s>` to map to "in INSERT MODE, `press <ESC>` to enter NORMAL MODE; `type ':w';<Enter>` and return to INSERT MODE to append text"
- `<C-o>` (letter O, not zero) to do the same. (It seems `vim` has already mapped this to `<Esc>`.)
- If I can't use `<C-s>` or `<C-o>`, then use `<F2>`.
- `<Alt-X>` (or `<Alt-F>X`) to map to "In INSERT MODE, `press <ESC>` to enter NORMAL MODE; `type ':q';<Enter>`"
- `<C-x>` to do the same as above.

What I have is this: `imap <C-s>=<C-[>:w<Enter>a` (or `inoremap <C-S> <Esc>:w<CR>a`)

Even if I precede `<C-[>` with `<C-V>`, pressing `<C-s>` results in `^S` being typed instead of saving the file.

I have read the [Mapping Keys in Vim](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)) tutorial on Vim Tips, but I haven't gleaned anything helpful from it. (I'm not sure whether I need to include the `=`, `type` or `press` instructions.) I've yet to try the solution proposed to [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13804/insert-mode-keymaps-custom-keymaps-just-insert-characters-of-combination-when-t) that seems to describe the issue I'm facing (because it's not clear if it resolves the issue).

I don't want to read two books (one on `vim` itself and another on VimScript) *just* to be able to create shortcuts for common commands that require a few more keystrokes. (The irony of typing all this here instead of just getting on with using colon commands is not lost on me.)

In case it makes a difference, I'm using `vim` 8.2.1847 on Ubuntu 22.04 running through WSL.

Comment: Here we go: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/mswin.vim But it is rather much more beneficial to start using Vim native keys instead of trying to force the existing MS-Windows keybindings to Vim.

Comment: Thank vou. In an ideal world, I would start using Vim from scratch, free from all the bad habits I've picked up by using Windows since I was old enough to sit up and type my own name. However, old habits die hard. While doing things the *right* way is always harder and/or takes longer, I've worked as a SW and Web developer for many years, so I'm lazy AF (one of the great virtues, although I'm not so good with the other two) and will go for the easy route if there is one.

Comment: A similar question (OP was coming from VS Code) was asked a while ago and I wrote a rather lengthy answer devoid of solid advice. You may or may not find it useful: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/41902/using-vscode-key-bindings-inside-vim/41907#41907

Comment: Or you could use Vim how it is supposed to be used. Laziness is not a valid excuse for anything.

Comment: FTR, I think learning Vim properly *is* the lazy (and best) route. Some fancy mappings may help short-term but a few weeks in, they will get in your way and hamper your productivity. The earlier you drop the dead weight, the better. And no, you don't need to read two books, `vimtutor` should be enough to get you started.

Comment: @romainl If it wasn't for laziness, neither Douglas Adams nor I would spend many frustrating days vainly programming a computer to do some tedious task we could do by hand in ten to fifteen minutes. (Anything that takes less than ten minutes to do manually is not worth writing code to automate it.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ChristianBrabant for directing me to the [mswin.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/mswin.vim) file in the GitHub repo for `vim`, I found that for which I was looking and added it (slightly modified) to `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Add key mappings for those familiar to MS Windows
" backspace in Visual mode deletes selection
vnoremap <BS> d

if has("clipboard")
    " In visual mode, CTRL-X is Cut. In normal mode, it's exit/quit.
    vnoremap <C-X> "+x
    noremap <C-X> :q<CR>
    noremap <F4> :q<CR>

    " CTRL-C is Copy
    vnoremap <C-C> "+y

    " CTRL-V and SHIFT-Insert are Paste
    map <C-V> "+gP
    map <S-Insert> "+gP
    cmap <C-V> <C-R>+
    cmap <S-Insert> <C-R>+
endif

" Use CTRL-S for saving, also in Insert mode (<C-O> doesn't work well when
" using completions).
noremap <C-S> :update<CR>
noremap <F2> :update<CR>
vnoremap <C-S> <C-C>:update<CR>
vnoremap <F2> <C-C>:update<CR>
inoremap <C-S> <Esc>:update<CR>gi
inoremap <F2> <Esc>:update<CR>gi
```

There's a lot more in that file, but the above is the code I want.

Comment: The file `mswin.vim` comes with Vim. Read `:help mswin.vim` and use it the way it's described there: `source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim`. That's the only line you need in your `vimrc`.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't necessarily want all the other stuff that's there and I'm not going to fork the project just to make a slight customisation to one file (which I'll then have to maintain separately from upstream). I'd probably end up overriding it in `~/.vimrc` anyway.